# Extracting multiple lines of data between two delimiters

Tags: bash, shell

I have a log file containing multiple lines of data. I need to extract and the all the lines between the delimiters and save it to the output file

input.log

```
Some data 
<delim_begin>ABC<delim_end>
some data
<delim_begin>DEF<delim_end>
some data
```

The output.log file should look like

```
ABC

DEF
```

I tried this code but it does not work, it prints all the content of input.log

```
sed 's/<delim_begin>\(.*\)<delim_end>/\1/g' input.log > output.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do it using custom field separator:

```
awk -F '<(delim_begin|delim_end)>' 'NF>2{print $2}' file
ABC
DEF
```

Using `grep -P` (PCRE):

```
grep -oP '(?<=<delim_begin>).*(?=<delim_end>)' file
ABC
DEF
```

Comment: I tried both the methods but all I get is empty output.log file

Answer (score 0):

`sed` alternative

```
$ sed -nr 's/<delim_begin>(.*)<delim_end>/\1/p' file

ABC
DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

`cat file | awk -F '<(delim_begin|delim_end)>' '{print $2}'`

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/660921) ;-) Just using `awk -F ... file` also works ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command -

`cat file  | grep "<delim_begin>.*<delim_end>" | sed 's/<delim_begin>//g' | sed 's/<delim_end>//' > output.log`